# Java RegExp - Extracting only numbers from a webpage

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a webpage converted to a string and I'm trying to extract three numbers from it from this line.

```
<td class="col_stat">1</td><td class="col_stat">0</td><td class="col_stat">1</td>
```

From the line above I already have it extracting the first '1' using this

```
String filePattern = "<td class=\"col_stat\">(.+)</td>";
    pattern = Pattern.compile(filePattern);
    matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    if(matcher.find()){
        String number = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(number);
    }
```

Now what I want to do is extract the 0 and the last 1 but anytime I try edit the regular expression above it just outputs the complete webpage on the console. Anyone have any suggestions?? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex matching is greedy, try this instead (looking only for `(\d+)` instead of `(.+)` (which matches everything until the last `</td>`):

```
String text = 
    "<td class=\"col_stat\">1</td>" + 
    "<td class=\"col_stat\">0</td>" + 
    "<td class=\"col_stat\">1</td>";
String filePattern = "<td class=\"col_stat\">(\\d+)</td>";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(filePattern);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find())
{
    String number = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

On a related note, I completely agree with other's suggestions to use a more structured approach to interpreting HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Given that using regexps on HTML/XML is a notorious gotcha (see here for the [definitive answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)), I'd recommend doing this *reliably* using an HTML parser (e.g. [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) - although it's a HTML pretty-printer, it also provides a DOM interface to the document)

Answer (score 1):

```
<td class=\"col_stat\">(.+)</td>
```

this regex is greedy. If you wish to make it work with numbers - change it as:

```
<td class=\"col_stat\">(\\d+?)</td>
```

and I'd rather suggest to use XPath for such kind of matching, see Saxon and TagSoup

Answer (score 0):

This is because your matcher is [greedy](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/GreedyAndNonGreedyMatching.shtml). You need a non-greedy matcher to fix this.

```
String text = "<td class=\"col_stat\">1</td><td class=\"col_stat\">0</td><td class=\"col_stat\">1</td>";

    String filePattern = "<td class=\"col_stat\">(.+?)</td>";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(filePattern);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String number = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(number);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression:

```
<td class="col_stat">(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)[^\d]+(\d+)
```

This does the following:

1. search for your start string
2. select a chain of decimals
3. skip any NON-decimals
4. select a chain of decimals
5. skip any NON-decimals
6. select a chain of decimals